# What is ParseServer's Maximum class limit?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I was wondering how many classes could I use within ParseServer, and if there is a max limit (lower tier usage).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any hard limits. You may see dashboard performance issues if you have a ton of classes. I haven't played around with adding a ton of classes to a database. Realistically how many do you think you'd have? If you're dynamically creating classes, there's probably a more efficient way to do what you need.

Also what do you mean lower tier usage? Parse-server is open source and doesn't have tiers. Wherever you host mongo may, but parse-server itself does not.

Comment: I'm in a situation where if I had a class that represented one users data then when querying data relevant to him it would take a lot less time than if I had one massive class that handled everyone's data.

Comment: That sounds like a poor implementation to me, that would be better managed with proper indexing of your DB based on queries you'd need to make and better setup how you're formatting that data, perhaps using custom JSON Objects as fields on your Parse Objects.

I truly can't imagine a case where it's more efficient to have a custom class for every user. I don't think anyone would recommend that.